# Create variable whose size increases inside a for loop

Tags: python

I have a for loop which does a logical computation on the rows of a large matrix and determines if each row is "good" or "bad". If it is good, then I want to make a copy of this row and store it in a new matrix, denoted "store". If it is bad, then I do not want to store it.

I have attempted to implement this with a simple for loop with an if loop inside:

```py
for i in range(len(x))
    a = function(x[i])
    if a == 1
        store[i] = x[i]
```

However, this gives me an error, saying the variable "store" is not defined. I was able to define variables in this way in MATLAB, but does this not work in Python? Is there a way around this, other than running the for loop twice, once to determine how many "good" rows there are, then defining the variable store, and then running it the second time? I want to avoid this if possible because this makes the entire program very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a list with the proper length before assigning to it:

```
store = [0] * len(x)
```

But to tell the truth, that's not the most idiomatic way to traverse and fill a list in Python, this looks better:

```
store = []
for e in x
    a = function(e)
    if a == 1
        store.append(e)
```

Or even better, let's use a list comprehension:

```
store = [e for e in x if function(e) == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the append method, but it seems to overwrite stuff in the list. I told the code to print the variable "store" at each step, and it displayed this:
[[row 1]] ; [[row 2], [row 2]] ; [[row 3], [row 3], [row 3]] ; ... (where ; represents a new line). Any fixes for this?

Comment: append doesn't overwrite stuff, it just adds items to the end of the list. It's quite possible that the problem is with the contents of the list `x` or the way you created list `x`. Make sure you're using my code exactly as it is above, or better, use the list comprehension option, which is the recommended. I can't help you any more without seeing the code that you're executing and the contents of `x`.

Comment: I accepted your answer, as it does answer my original question of how to generate lists with increasing size. I also edited my answer with the actual code I am running, to see if you can maybe pinpoint the cause of this problem? I assume its being caused by one of the for loops overwriting it, but I don't see really what's wrong

Comment: The code is still missing some values and a function. A good question in Stack Overflow should allow people to just copy, paste it and run it, because otherwise we won't be able to reproduce the problem. All I can _guess_ is that you're assigning something wrong in `x0`, but again, it's not a problem with `append()`

Comment: You should post a new question with this new problem, and now make sure that the code can be executed by anybody, including all the missing values that at the moment make it impossible for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have done as you suggested, the new question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57580950/7944165). I also removed the edit on this question.

Answer (score 1):

If a list/ variable `store` is not defined prior to using it, Python raises an error. So, define `store` with

```py
store = []
```

And use `store.append(i)`.

Comment: Yeah I tried this, but then this gives an out of range error

Comment: Use ```store.append(i)```

Comment: ```range```  takes the first value as 1. So, ```i``` is assigned the value of 1. But the list is of length 0, thus the out of range error.