# Code keeps overwriting entries in array when using .append() to try to add new entries

Tags: python

I originally asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57573365/7944165) asking about fixing a problem I was having with variables of increasing size (the variable `store` that appears towards the end of the code). Implementing the append feature worked to make the variable grow in size, but for some reason, rather than adding the new element as I wanted, the program did this while also overwriting any existing entries in `store` with the same element. The answerer on that question suggested I post a new question, with the full code so that the error is reproducible.

**The code:**

```py
from math import floor


def function(x):
    y = sorted(x)  # python sorts this ascending using the sorted function
    y2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y2[i] = y[len(y) - i - 1]  # this reverses the order of elements in the vector, so it is descending
    m = sum(x) / 11
    a = 0
    for i in range(11):
        if y2[i] >= m:
            a = a + 1
    d = 0
    for i in range(a):
        dummy = y2[i] - m
        d = d + dummy
    rating = round(11 * m + d) / 11
    return floor(rating)


def combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    # combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)


def testfn(y, aim):
    leny = len(y)
    nlen = 11 - leny
    choiceset = [81, 82, 83, 84, 85]
    combs = combinations_with_replacement(choiceset, nlen)
    counter = 0
    for i in combs:
        counter = counter + 1
    noofcombs = counter
    z = [[0 for col in range(nlen)] for row in range(noofcombs)]
    combs = combinations_with_replacement(choiceset, nlen) # not sure why i need to include this again, but z doesn't
    # get defined properly without this line
    counter = 0
    for i in combs:
        z[counter] = list(i)
        counter = counter + 1
    store = []
    x0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for j in range(noofcombs):
        for i1 in range(leny):
            x0[i1] = y[i1] # fills in the rest of the elements of x0 using one of the rows of z
        for i2 in range(nlen):
            x0[i2 + leny] = z[j][i2] # outputs a weighted average of the elements of the vector x0
        var = function(x0)
        if var >= aim - 0.2:
            print(x0) # this is where the error is
            store.append(x0)
            print(store) # this is where the error is


testfn([83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82], 83)
```

**The problem:**

My problem is with the code towards the end (lines 55 and onwards). I don't think the first two functions have any problems, I have only included them so the code is reproducible (though it's possible the error is there). I have put a print statement at lines 65, 67 so the error is properly displayed. The first few things the function returns are:

```py
[83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 84]
[[83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 84]]
[83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 85]
[[83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 85], [83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 85]]
```

The first entry has clearly been overwritten, I expected the 4th line to read

```py
[[83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 84], [83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 81, 85]]
```

Looking at further returns shows the overwriting continues, and I am eventually left with an array containing loads of copies of `[83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 85, 85, 85]`, which is not what I want.

---

By the way, in case you're wondering, the reason I keep overwriting the first few elements of x0 with the elements of y is because some part of the code seems to be causing the vector x0 to become ordered (descending), so overwriting ensures those elements always stay.

Comment: Fix the immediate problem with `store.append(x0[:])`.  This makes a shallow copy of `x0` and appends that instead of the original list.

Comment: A general node I'd recommend giving more meaningful names to variables. Think about if you looked at this a month from now, will you remember what this does and why you did it that way?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes, I have been thinking this too. I made this code in MATLAB 4 years ago (when I was quite new to coding), and have been trying to adjust it to python, but doing so hasn't been easy due to the variable names. I think I did it because it was quicker to type. In my newer pieces of code, I do have better variable names

Comment: @Prune thanks, that does the trick! I'll also take a look at the duplicate question, think I should be able to learn a lot from it.